# possible to reference CSS selector in code-behind ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, css-selectors, code-behind

Let's say I have this HTML markup on an aspx page:

```
      <div id = 'logo-container' class='foo'>
          <img alt='logo' src ="images/foo.png" />
      </div>
```

Pure html, **not** runat=server.

Is it possible, *in aspx code-behind*, to refer to a DOM element using CSS selectors? Could you get a reference to the IMG doing something like this:

```
 foreach element in GetElement("#logo-container img")
  {
       do something with element, e.g. change a style attribute
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot, unfortunately. You'd be beter off doing it the intended way. If you need to access the controls in code-behind, just add the `runat="server"` attribute.

Why don't you want to run the controls at the server, considering that you need to access them in the code-behind? Are you worried about the auto-generated IDs? If so, you can resolve this by setting `ClientIDMode` to *static*.

If you do run the control at the server, you should be able to find the controls with that class using LINQ like this:

```
var ctrls = pnlControls.Controls.OfType<WebControl>().Where(i => i.CssClass == "logo-container");
```

**Note:** You can Replace `WebControl` with a more specific control if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - No. If the control is not set to runat="server", you cannot access it from the code behind. However, you can access the element using Javascript and then call a server-side method to do whatever logic you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I feel better Solution is :

If you really want to change the style/css class you can better go for jquery and customize the way you want it.